# Troubles with rxgraph, rxplot, and rxbag on OSX with Homebrew and Electric

Tags: rxtools, macos, rxplot, rxgraph, homebrew

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,
I followed the installation instructions for OSX (Lion) using Homebrew and many things are working great. However, I'm unable to get rxgraph, rxplot, or rxbag to work.

rx-1.6.1

ROS Electric

OSX Lion

Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jul 31 2011, 19:30:53)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin

---

**RXGRAPH**

rxgraph fails because the python gobject library is missing:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ptf/Work/ethz/vc_ros/ros/bin/rxgraph", line 35, in 
    import rxgraph
  File "/Users/ptf/Work/ethz/vc_ros/rx/rxgraph/src/rxgraph/__init__.py", line 37, in 
    import rxgraph.impl
  File "/Users/ptf/Work/ethz/vc_ros/rx/rxgraph/src/rxgraph/impl.py", line 46, in 
    from rxgraph.viewer import RxGraphViewerFrame
  File "/Users/ptf/Work/ethz/vc_ros/rx/rxgraph/src/rxgraph/viewer.py", line 34, in 
    import xdot
  File "/Users/ptf/Work/ethz/vc_ros/rx/xdot/src/xdot/__init__.py", line 2, in 
    import wxxdot
  File "/Users/ptf/Work/ethz/vc_ros/rx/xdot/src/xdot/wxxdot.py", line 22, in 
    from xdot import *
  File "/Users/ptf/Work/ethz/vc_ros/rx/xdot/src/xdot/xdot.py", line 34, in 
    import gobject
ImportError: No module named gobject
```

---

**RXPLOT**

rxplot crashes with a nasty looking error, but this already has an open ticket.

https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3777

---

**RXBAG**

rxbag exits with an informative error message:

```
> rxbag
This application requires wxPython version 2.8
```

As far as I can tell, the Homebrew instructions install wxPython 2.9. So, when I change the python code to check for 2.9, it fails downstream when trying to load pycairo:

```
> rxbag
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ptf/Work/ethz/vc_ros/ros/bin/rxbag", line 38, in 
    import rxbag
  File "/Users/ptf/Work/ethz/vc_ros/rx/rxbag/src/rxbag/__init__.py", line 34, in 
    from rxbag_main import rxbag_main
  File "/Users/ptf/Work/ethz/vc_ros/rx/rxbag/src/rxbag/rxbag_main.py", line 56, in 
    import wx.lib.wxcairo
  File "/usr/local/lib/wxPython-2.9.2.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.9.2-osx_cocoa/wx/lib/wxcairo.py", line 54, in 
    import cairo
ImportError: No module named cairo
```

---

I assume the rxplot problem is a separate issue, but is there something wrong with my Python installation that I am missing cairo and gobject?

Thanks for your help!

Paul

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12619/troubles-with-rxgraph,-rxplot,-and-rxbag-on-osx-with-homebrew-and-electric./) by [ptf](https://answers.ros.org/users/1514/ptf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-01-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These packages are known not to work currently due to a problem with gtk.  In the mean time, there are some similar tools provided by ros_gui:

http://www.ros.org/browse/stack.php?name=ros_gui

That work very well on the Mac.

There are some related tickets open:

https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3777

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2012-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2